# Using dm-cache for transparent ongoing backup

Tags: mdadm, cache, ssd, block-device, bcache

Is there any chance to use dm-cache for ongoing SSD backup?

I want to have very fast and cheap eventually consistent failure resistant partition.

Use case:

We have regular ssd (1Gb) (cache) + hdd (1Gb) (origin) installation.
If ssd fails it should be able to take last available snapshot from hdd.
If hdd fails we have fully worked filesystem on ssd.

I dont want to use any manual snapshots and care about scheduling.

Key question is if cache size = origin size, could origin be fully restored automatically?

Comment: Why not just buy a 2nd SSD and use some form of RAID-1 aka mirroring (with mdadm, lvm, btrfs, or zfs, etc)?   Drive mirroring is a tried and tested technology that Just Works.   DIY with dm-cache isn't (not for this kind of task, anyway).  BTW, with btrfs or zfs you can also perform regular incremental backups with, `btrfs send` or `zfs send` to a remote machine...and (unlike tar or rsync) they're a low-impact backup that can be performed multiple times per hour without unduly affecting overall system performance.

Comment: Because it is just 2 times more expensive

Comment: Yes. there's a cost to improve the safety of your data.  IMO, it's worth every cent. Personally, I'd never store anything important on anything less than a mirrored pair of drives (I use ZFS - gives me snapshots, compression, error correction, and lots of other useful stuff as well as mirroring) in addition to regular backups.   If you want to do it cheaper, use 2 x HDDs and then add a smallish fast SSD for caching (e.g. with mdadm+bcache, or ZFS can use SSDs to cache HDD pools).

Comment: I want hdd raid0 + ssd (dm-cache) 

sensitive data on ssd + backed up by hdd

Comment: if you want raid-0 then you are effectively saying "I do not care at all about my data. It is garbage and if I lost it all I wouldn't care in the slighest".

Comment: Seems you do not want to understand what I mean... I need raid0 on hdd, and some kind of raid1 on ssd + raid0(hdd) implemented via dm-cache

Comment: No, I'm trying to give you useful advice that what you mean and what you want are dangerous and will inevitably destroy your data at some time in the future.   It's your data, however, so feel free to do insanely risky things with it.  But do so **knowing** that it is insanely risky.  Enjoy. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't work. There's no method for "pushing" non-dirty blocks in the cache to the origin device. You will have dirty blocks temporarily which have not been written to the origin device, which you can flush to the origin device using the "cleaner" cache option, but there's not way to re-create the origin device with a cache device (even if it is the same size).

Answer (score 0):

Seems it could be used if I find a way to mark all blocks in cache metadata as dirty and then demote them to new hdd in case of origin hdd failure.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/cache.txt